# How to pick items following multiple conditions

Tags: algorithm, set, distance

I am creating a small piece of software and came across a conceptual problem. I will try to explain the situation with a small example:

- I have a coordinate system which contains multiple points.
- Each point is described by its position on the x and y axis (so far so normal) and can either be blue or red.
- Now I want to create events.
- Each event contains one blue and one red point and there are several conditions on how to pick them.

  - E.g.: the sum of blue(x) and red(x) *(=the x values of the blue and the red point)* must be even.
  - At the same time, there might be a condition that the checksum of the y values must not be a prime number.
- Each point can be part of multiple events.
- In my situation every point has specific resources that are "used" when an event is created and the point can be part of new events as long as it has the required amount of resources.

What I need is to create as many events as possible (that is until the resources of either the blue or the red group are exhausted). Let's assume I have 2 red and 2 blue points. Yes and No means if they satisfy the given conditions:

```
B1  R1  Yes
B1  R2  Yes
B2  R1  Yes
B2  R2  No
```

If I match B1 and R1 (the top of each list), I only get one event as B2 and R2 don't match. On the other hand, if I match B1 with R2 and B2 with R1 I receive 2 events. This is what I need.

Also, the average distance (from the blue point to the red point) of my events should be a low as possible.

I thought about creating events by randomly picking blue and red points as long as they match the conditions, do the whole process multiple times and keep the result with the highest amount of events and the lowest average distance. But I don't really like it, as I cannot provide any statement about the result quality. Also the result will not be deterministic.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: No. I am creating a planning tool for attacks in an online game.

Comment: event = pair of points? => optimal set of pairs => isn't this an NP-something problem?

Comment: I have updated the question to clarify the desired outcome. I might have up to 5000 red and maybe about 300 blue points. That should yield about 2000 events.

Comment: This question is underspecified. What's missing is the way that resources-per-event is calculated and what all event selection criteria are exactly. Depending on what these are, finding an optimal answer may or may not have an efficient algorithm.

Comment: Also, there's no guarantee at all that there's a unique optimal solution, nor that the best algorithm is deterministic.

Comment: can the same event happen twice?

Comment: @eh9, why is that important? Every point has a resource object. When I create an event I pick a blue point, check the resources it requires, pick a red point and deduct the resources from its resource object. The points have no knowledge on how the deduct method is implemented. The second criteria is that the distance between points needs to be within certain intervals.

Comment: @deathApril, yes, there can be event with the same red and blue points that requires the same resources.

Comment: @Jan So every event has the same cost, and these costs are simply added up for each node? The difference is between linear and non-linear costs, which would require different optimization techniques.

Answer (score 0):

when in doubt, start with brute force *(at least so you can check the validity of other solution)* - on really small test data sets *(e.g. 4+3 points => n=4*3 possible pairs):

1. from the product of all possible pairs create an array of possible events *(list of blue-red pairs that match the criteria, also precompute the distances in this step)*

    - worst case size `n = red_count * blue_count`
2. copy this array into a set of sets, each having only 1 event: `{{(r1,b1)}, {(r1,b2)}, ...}`
3. for each set:

   - update resources on the points *(stored separatelly for each set of course)*
   - if there are still resources to match, split current set by adding  1 more pair *(do it for each pair that can be added)* and remove the current uncomplete set, like this:

     ```
     4 sets of 1 event     10 sets of 2 events
     e1 e2 e3 e4              e1 e2 e3 e4
     x  x  x  x            e1 x  x  x  x
                       ->  e2    x  x  x
                           e3       x  x
                           e4          x
     ```
   - repeat until no set can be improved by a new pair (no more resources or all pairs used)

=> worst case **O(n<sup>2k</sup>)** *(n=r*b=all possible red/blue pairs, k = no. of events in biggest set)*

then get inspired by [global optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_optimization) techniques, not sure how your requirements can be combined without more detailed specification, thought...

steps 1 and 2 are O(n) => probably acceptable for `5000*300 = 1.5m` pairs

i would try to **sort the array of events by distance** - *O(nlogn)* - and **use only `x` shortest events as a starting point** for my heuristic algorithms (test 1-10 shortest to see the performance / accuracy tradeoffs) + keep only `x` shortest sets after splits ...

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting problem, but there are so many parameters to consider it seems.

As the first step, I'd try to simplify the presentation of the problem / parameters using a *compatibility matrix*. The rows of the matrix will correspond to the blue points, and columns of the matrix will represent red points. For your sample problem, the matrix would be something like below:

```
     R1    R2

B1   1     1

B2   1     0
```

So, this matrix represents which points can be paired up with which other points to make events.

Next, let's try to solve the sample problem in your description with this matrix. This can be done using a bit of dynamic programming:

1. Assume that all the `R` points are present but the only blue point available is `B1`. Build a *solution vector* listing the possible combinations. So you'll get `[(R1, B1)], [(R2, B1)]`.
2. Now we **incrementally** introduce `B2` into the solution vector built in the previous step. For the first component of the solution vector, note that `R1` was already used up in the previous step and `R2` cannot be pared with `B2`, so this solution cannot be improved. However the second component of the solution vector can be improved because `(R1, B2)` can be added to it. So we get the final solution vector `[(R1, B1)],[(R2, B1), (R1, B2)]`.
3. Now you can count individual components of the solution vector and pick the one which has the most number of items in it (or events, in your case).

I think it's possible to extend this approach to the full version of your problem, but it will need a lot more house-keeping (since you have to keep track of resource usage as well). Unlike in your sample, pairing up `R1` with `B1` in the first step doesn't necessarily mean that `R1` is finished... it might have enough resources so that it can be reused.

I hope this will give you some insight at the least. Good luck! :)